# i686-elf-gcc CreateProcess error (No such file or directory)

Tags: c++, gcc, createprocess

So im trying to compile my .cpp code with i686-elf-gcc. I keep trying to compile but everything else just wouldent work. So in a form i saw -v displayed what was happening. So i was wondering if anyone could look at my code/log to see. If anyone is wondering where its from http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones. This was the tutorial I was following. 
 Im using Windows 10 in order to compile

```
i686-elf-g++ -v -c kernel.cpp -o kernel.o -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=i686-elf-g++
Target: i686-elf
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --target=i686-elf --prefix=/srcgcc/ghost-i686-elf-tools --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-o' '..\build\kernel.o' '-ffreestanding' '-O2' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-fno-exceptions' '-fno-rtti' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 cc1plus -quiet -v -iprefix f:\c to assembly\i686-elf\../lib/gcc/i686-elf/4.8.2/ ..\source\kernel.cpp -quiet -dumpbase kernel.cpp -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase-strip ..\build\kernel.o -O2 -Wall -Wextra -version -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -o C:\Users\LOGANR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cca5r8Jq.s
i686-elf-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
```

Kernel.cpp

```
/* Surely you will remove the processor conditionals and this comment
   appropriately depending on whether or not you use C++. */
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#include <stdbool.h> /* C doesn't have booleans by default. */
#endif
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* Check if the compiler thinks we are targeting the wrong operating system. */
#if defined(__linux__)
#error "You are not using a cross-compiler, you will most certainly run into trouble"
#endif

/* This tutorial will only work for the 32-bit ix86 targets. */
#if !defined(__i386__)
#error "This tutorial needs to be compiled with a ix86-elf compiler"
#endif

/* Hardware text mode color constants. */
enum vga_color {
    VGA_COLOR_BLACK = 0,
    VGA_COLOR_BLUE = 1,
    VGA_COLOR_GREEN = 2,
    VGA_COLOR_CYAN = 3,
    VGA_COLOR_RED = 4,
    VGA_COLOR_MAGENTA = 5,
    VGA_COLOR_BROWN = 6,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = 7,
    VGA_COLOR_DARK_GREY = 8,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BLUE = 9,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREEN = 10,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_CYAN = 11,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_RED = 12,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_MAGENTA = 13,
    VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_BROWN = 14,
    VGA_COLOR_WHITE = 15,
};

static inline uint8_t vga_entry_color(enum vga_color fg, enum vga_color bg) {
    return fg | bg << 4;
}

static inline uint16_t vga_entry(unsigned char uc, uint8_t color) {
    return (uint16_t) uc | (uint16_t) color << 8;
}

size_t strlen(const char* str) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (str[len])
        len++;
    return len;
}

static const size_t VGA_WIDTH = 80;
static const size_t VGA_HEIGHT = 25;

size_t terminal_row;
size_t terminal_column;
uint8_t terminal_color;
uint16_t* terminal_buffer;

void terminal_initialize(void) {
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_column = 0;
    terminal_color = vga_entry_color(VGA_COLOR_LIGHT_GREY, VGA_COLOR_BLACK);
    terminal_buffer = (uint16_t*) 0xB8000;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++) {
            const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
            terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(' ', terminal_color);
        }
    }
}

void terminal_setcolor(uint8_t color) {
    terminal_color = color;
}

void terminal_putentryat(char c, uint8_t color, size_t x, size_t y) {
    const size_t index = y * VGA_WIDTH + x;
    terminal_buffer[index] = vga_entry(c, color);
}

void terminal_putchar(char c) {
    terminal_putentryat(c, terminal_color, terminal_column, terminal_row);
    if (++terminal_column == VGA_WIDTH) {
        terminal_column = 0;
        if (++terminal_row == VGA_HEIGHT)
            terminal_row = 0;
    }
}

void terminal_write(const char* data, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        terminal_putchar(data[i]);
}

void terminal_writestring(const char* data) {
    terminal_write(data, strlen(data));
}

#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" /* Use C linkage for kernel_main. */
#endif
void kernel_main(void) {
    /* Initialize terminal interface */
    terminal_initialize();

    /* Newline support is left as an exercise. */
    terminal_writestring("Hello, kernel World!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set of 32 bit libraries + 32 -bit ldso. 
On ubuntu try

apt-get install libc6-i386

Comment: Im using windows 10.

Comment: in that case you should be using WSL.